# Google map : How to create a custom infowindow used custom overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

i'm a newbie in javascript

use custom overlay but always detect 'cannot read property 'setContent' of undefined'

my javascript code is https://github.com/SaneMethod/CGWin/blob/master/src/cGWin.js

and i use jquery because of parsing Exel file

```
////https://github.com/SaneMethod/CGWin/blob/master/src/cGWin.js/////
function  GenCustomWindow () {
    var CustomWindow = function () {
    ....
    }
}
////parsing code////
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "",
        datatype: "text",
        success: function (data) { processData(data); }
    });
});    
function processData(allText) {
        ....
    var info = new GenCustomWindow();
    for(i = 0;i < name.length;i++)
    {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(a, b),
            map: map,
            icon: markerImage,
            optimized: false
        });            
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                content =
                    '<div class="iw-title">' +
                    name[i] + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="iw-content">' +
                    '<div class="iw-subTitle">' + add[i] + '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="iw-bottom-gradient"></div>' +
                    '</div>';
                info.CustomWindow.setContent('content');
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}
```

there is always error in info.CustomWindow.setContent

why is this code an error?

and can you recommend another custom infowindow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GenCustomWindow()` returns a `CustomWindow`, which means `info` is alread a `CustomWindow`.

Change

```
info.CustomWindow.setContent('content');
```

to

```
info.setContent('content');
```

And everything should work fine.